# disappearing app window after few sec after run

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I installed figma (figma-bin) from AUR and i have problem like on [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCiqN7ZMcFo&feature=youtu.be)

I have no idea why this work like this.
I tried with figma-linux-bin too but it's the same result.
Also upgrade my electron and it's still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try simple fixes like updating your operating system or checking to see if an antivirus software may be causing some conflict. If that doesn't help, check to see if any software dependencies are missing which can cause an application to close unexpectedly. If all that fails to solve the problem, I suggest reaching out to the application developer.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/YLcRwGm.png   journalctl